# What is the meaning of “Tu me présenteras ton adjoint”?

Tags: grammaire, sens, compléments

I have a sentence in my French workbook which has to be converted into *impératif* and the highlighted words should be replaced by personal pronouns. The sentence is:

> Tu me présenteras **ton adjoint**.

I guess this means 'You will present me as your assistant' or 'You will present me your assistant.'

So is the given sentence correct and if yes, what does it mean?

Comment: This seems like a case of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/208568), since I think you actually want to know about pronouns and how to turn a declaration into an order.

Answer (score 3):

The second answer is correct: “You will present me your assistant.”

To put it simply, in the sentence:

> Tu me présenteras ton adjoint.

there is no particle that would play the role of “as” in the  French sentence.

The sentence corresponding to

> You will present me as your assistant.

would be

> Tu me présenteras **comme** ton adjoint.

Comment: so the imperatif of that (using personal pronouns) would be: présentez-moi te!

Comment: First answer could also be translated this way: “Tu me présenteras en tant qu'adjoint (/ en tant que ton adjoint)“. @user2468338: No, it's: “Présentez-moi cette personne.” or, with a pronoun, “Présentez-le moi (/ Présentez-la moi)”. To ask someone to introduce himself/herself: “Présente-toi” (or “Présentez-vous”).

Comment: No. Présentez is imperative for the second person plural; you want second-person singular. Also the subject of the original sentence (Tu) disappears in the imperative : for example, "Tu parles fort" becomes "Parle fort", nothing more. Hope this helps.

Comment: so what is the correct answer?

Comment: The correct answer to your exercise would be "Présente-le moi".

Comment: @Jhyn Doesn’t “*comme*” fill exactly the same purpose as “as” in your sentence?

Comment: @Édouard It does. I am referring to his sentence (in the question), which does not contain "as".

Comment: @Jhyn Oh, OK. I didn’t find it very clear, so I tried to make it more self-explanatory. Don’t hesitate to revert if you mind my edit.

Comment: @user2468338: The present question does not ask for the answer to your exercise. This is fine. Now, if you also want the answer to this exercise please ask it in a new question because it's a completely different question. And the exact spelling for this answer is not known by many French-speakers.

Comment: @user2468338 If you want us to help with your exercise, you should ask about it directly in a [new question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).